# Dynamic source / adjust array reference according to last col

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, pivot-table

I am comparing an ID to two pivot tables and then returning the matched value from specific columns by each pivot table.

Previously, the pivot tables had a fixed count of columns, but now I am faced with the pivot tables varying in terms of the last column.

My attempt was to use the code line

```
   LastColContract = wsContractPivot.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

in order to find the last column in the ContractPivot and then change the line

```
rwReport.Columns("G").Resize(1, 7).Value = _
```

to

```
rwReport.Columns("G").Resize(1, lastColContract).Value = _
```

but I am struggling with telling Excel to then expand the array columns to add additional columns after H.

So if lastcol is 10, then I need the code to start listing 10 columns starting with Column B.
if lastcol is 12, then 12 columns from B etc.

```
    For Each c In wsReport.Range("F3", wsReport.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)).Cells
    
    c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 50).ClearContents
    
    MfrName = c.Value 'read this once....
    Set rwReport = c.EntireRow
    
    '1st Database Match "ContractSpend"
    m = Application.Match(MfrName, wsContractPivot.Columns("A"), 0)
    If Not IsError(m) Then
       With wsContractPivot.Rows(m)
        
        'starting column
                rwReport.Columns("G").Resize(1, 7).Value = _
               Array(.Columns("B").Value, .Columns("C").Value, _
                     .Columns("D").Value, .Columns("E").Value, _
                     .Columns("F").Value, .Columns("G").Value, .Columns("H").Value)
            'Extended Cost
            
        End With
    Else
        'no match...
    End If
```

Comment: I'd start here - https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/  This should help you reference the relevant ranges in your code

Comment: thanks but I am having trouble adjusting the array references in a dynamic not static situation.

Comment: *if lastcol is 10, then I need the code to start listing 10 columns starting with Column B. if lastcol is 12, then 12 columns from B* you mean then 11 and 13? That sounds like `lastcol+1`

Comment: not exactly. When last col is 7, then I need to array refer to columns B,C,D,E,F,G,H. If last col is 10, I need to array reference columns B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K. I can't find a solution to tell the code to adjust the columns accordingly.

Comment: [Worksheet.Columns property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.columns) admits numbers... Wouldn't that work? or a loop?

Comment: `rwReport.Columns("G").Resize(1, 7).Value = wsContractPivot.Cells(m, "B").Resize(1, 7).Value`  There's no need to build an array using Array() unless you need to copy from non-contiguous columns, or to re-order them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
'...
'...
Set pt = wsContractPivot.PivotTables(1)    'or use specific name

'https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/
numCols = pt.TableRange1.Columns.Count - 1 'PT width-1

For Each c In wsReport.Range("F3", wsReport.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)).Cells
    
    c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 50).ClearContents
    
    MfrName = c.Value 'read this once....
    Set rwReport = c.EntireRow
    
    m = Application.Match(MfrName, wsContractPivot.Columns("A"), 0)
    
    If Not IsError(m) Then
       
       rwReport.Columns("G").Resize(1, numCols).Value = _
           wsContractPivot.Cells(m, "B").Resize(1, numCols).Value
       
    End If
Next c
'...
'...
```